# PDFs - Delete all pages except the 1st page in a PDF in a folder

Tags: windows, pdf, cmd

I really need some help
as my script works but makes a mess

```
@echo off
set OutputFilePath=trimmed

pushd 
for /r %%i in (*.pdf) do (
       pdftk "%%i" cat 1 output "%OutputFilePath%%%~ni-1stpage%%~xi"
)
popd
```

Can someone help to correct my script as follows

1. Have it scan only in the current directory, currently it goes also in sub folder and it also processes the files already done.

It can also by something brand new also in PowerShell or Python

Comment: Have you tried to modify the script as described on your own? Please share your efforts...

Comment: Near the end of the output from the command `FOR /?` there is information about using the loop variable such as `%%~ni` and `%%~xi`. Please investigate and see if you can change the script.

Comment: Thanks Lit that solved Q1 and Q3, i'm such a noob that i wasn't aware of that for FOR. `pdftk "%%i" cat 1 output "%OutputFilePath%%%~ni-1stpage%%~xi"` Now i need to keep it from stopping to look into my subfolders

Comment: Really find it interesting to see people down vote a question as the down voters have no clue about how or what i researched and how long, And the question was described simple enough to understand. especially at my beginners level.So they didn't ask and just started pressing the button. Correct me if i'm wrong as i'm just asking help as some one who's not working in the scripting business at all just doing this for myself to automate things

Comment: @Marco Hi, I didn't downvote, but as for your comment: "_the down voters have no clue about how or what i researched and how long_" That's why you have to share in your question how and what you researched. Please don't make assumptions like that and assume good intention.

Comment: i always research but as a newbie i get stuck many times and need some pointers. But down voters never looking at the question again and keeping the downed votes on it so the ticket will be closed isn't good intention to my opinion

Comment: LIt helped my guide my one my way with his answers and i now solved it.

Comment: @Marco Then you can post it as an answer in the answer box. Self-answers are encouraged and this will help other users as well. Adding "answered by Lit" in the question and changing it to show the solution is not the correct way, because the comment that helped answering it can be removed at any time and questions should not contain the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank Lit for your tips, worked with that to get the answer.
I created the following script

```
@echo off
set OutputFilePath=<output path>

pushd 
for %%i in (*.pdf) do (
    pdftk "%%i" cat 1 output "%OutputFilePath%%%~ni-1stpage%%~xi"
)
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to try this in PowerShell, the following might work.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path 'C:\src\t' -Filter '*.pdf' |
    ForEach-Object {
        pdftk $_.FullName cat 1 output "C:\pdf\new\dir\$($_.BaseName)-1stpage$($_.Extension)"
    }
```

Comment: Hi Lit thanks for the extra option. I like the Shell version updated with your tips better as i can move it around as it's for my quarterly administration so i can create it once and use it always :)